# ¿Como obtengo la Key aleatoria de un Document antes de enviarlo a Firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

estoy aprendiendo acerca de como obtener y guardar los datos en Cloud Firestore. Ahora mismo me encuentro en un problema porque quiero guardar el key de un documento como un campo mas.

Algo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aun no se como obtener ese Key.

Eh intentado obtenerlo con un `getId()`, similar a como lo sugieren las guías de Firebase, pero al ver el key que guarda es diferente.

Esta es la forma en la que estoy guardando los datos en Firestore:

```
public void saveMessage(Map<String, String> messageData) {

    final UserRegisterFirebaseObserver userRegisterFirebaseObserver = new UserRegisterFirebaseObserver();
  requestRepository.getSpecificMessagesDatabaseReference("K9vnzc7Qi5Lg1zY1NjPh","Rt2yKUzJKCRmKj5xP7rc")
            .set(messageData)
            .addOnSuccessListener(userRegisterFirebaseObserver)
            .addOnFailureListener(userRegisterFirebaseObserver);

}
```

Y esto es lo que hago en `requestRepository.getSpecificMessagesDatabaseReference()`

```
public DocumentReference getSpecificMessagesDatabaseReference(String requestKey, String chatKey) {
    return mDatabase.collection(REQUEST_COLLECTION_REFERENCE).document(requestKey).collection(CHAT_COLLECTION_REFERENCE).document(chatKey).collection(MESSAGE_COLLECTION_REFERENCE).document();
}
```

Con el `.document()` estoy creando un key aleatorio, pero no se como obtenerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya dí con la solucion.

Resulta que haciendo `.document().getId()`obtenía el key generado automáticamente en ese momento, y cuando hacia `.set(messageData)` se generaba otro key aleatorio para almacenarlo en Firestore por eso eran diferentes.

Para solucionarlo decidí utilizar `.add(messageData)`, así podía posteriormente en un `addOnSuccessListener()` actualizar el documento con el key dentro.

Así quedo mi codigo:

```
public void saveMessage(final Map<String, Object> messageData) {
    final MessageRegisterFirebaseObserver messageRegisterFirebaseObserver = new MessageRegisterFirebaseObserver();

    requestRepository.getSpecificMessagesDatabaseReference("K9vnzc7Qi5Lg1zY1NjPh", "Rt2yKUzJKCRmKj5xP7rc")
            .add(messageData)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    messageData.put("key", documentReference.getId());
                    documentReference.update(messageData)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(messageRegisterFirebaseObserver)
                            .addOnFailureListener(messageRegisterFirebaseObserver);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(messageRegisterFirebaseObserver);


}
```

y

```
public CollectionReference getSpecificMessagesDatabaseReference(String requestKey, String chatKey) {
    return mDatabase.collection(REQUEST_COLLECTION_REFERENCE).document(requestKey).collection(CHAT_COLLECTION_REFERENCE).document(chatKey).collection(MESSAGE_COLLECTION_REFERENCE);
}
```